# GROUP BY confusion

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2008-r2

I am pulling through some data in SQL Server and I would like to `GROUP BY` my results but cannot get it to work.

This is my current SQL statement:

```
SELECT
   PA01201.CUSTNMBR, 
   PA01201.PACONTNUMBER, 
   PA01201.PAcontid, 
   PA01100.CUSTNMBR AS Expr1, 
   PA01100.PAcontname, 
   PA01100.PAcontid AS Expr2, 
   PA01100.PACONTNUMBER AS Expr3, 
   PA01201.PAprojname, 
   PA01201.PAPROJNUMBER
   PA01201.Cost

FROM        
   PA01201 
INNER JOIN
   PA01100 ON PA01201.CUSTNMBR = PA01100.CUSTNMBR AND 
              PA01201.PACONTNUMBER = PA01100.PACONTNUMBER AND 
              PA01201.PAcontid = PA01100.PAcontid
```

It returns these results:

```
CUSTNMBR    PACONTNUMBER    PAcontid    Expr1   Pacontname  Expr2   Expr3   Paprojname  PAPROJNUMBER    Cost
AD001           8051    8051    AD001           Company 1   8051    8051    Project 1   08051P          951
AP001           8063    8063    AP001           Company 2   8063    8063    Project 2   08063P          2651
AR002           8096    8096    AR002           Company 3   8096    8096    Project 3   08096P          807
AR003           9033    9033    AR003           Company 4   9033    9033    Project 4   09033P          458
AS001           8013    8013    AS001           Company 5   8013    8013    Project 5   08013C          3297
AS001           8013    8013    AS001           Company 5   8013    8013    Project 5   08013P          48
AS001           8013    8013    AS001           Company 5   8013    8013    Project 5   08013P          641
AR002           8096    8096    AR002           Company 3   8096    8096    Project 3   08096P          1000
```

I would like to be able to group the result by `PAcontid`.

Can anyone advise the easiest way to do this?

When I try and insert a `GROUP BY` clause I get an error stating that the other columns (CUSTNMBR, PAPROJNUMBER) etc are not included in the clause????

Any help much appreciated.

All work is being done in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

---

Sorry for some reason my last column (Cost) didn;t come through.  I have updated my question to show the proper fields.  Basically what I am trying to do is get a total cost for each Pacontid.

I would like my results to look something like ........

```
CUSTNMBR    PACONTNUMBER    PAcontid    Expr1   Pacontname  Expr2   Expr3   Paprojname  PAPROJNUMBER    Cost
    AS001           8013    8013    AS001           Company 5   8013    8013    Project 5   08013P          3986
    AD001           8051    8051    AD001           Company 1   8051    8051    Project 1   08051P          951
    AP001           8063    8063    AP001           Company 2   8063    8063    Project 2   08063P          2651
    AR002           8096    8096    AR002           Company 3   8096    8096    Project 3   08096P          1807
    AR003           9033    9033    AR003           Company 4   9033    9033    Project 4   09033P          458
```

Is this possible in what I am trying to do?

Comment: can you add what you think the output should look like after this?  i think maybe you are using the word 'group by' differently...

Comment: [SQL GROUP BY Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: What is your desired end result? You can't group by PAcontid because the other columns are different - there is nothing to really group together - GROUP BY allows you to group together rows with columns that have the same value, and aggregate other columns based on that grouping. For example, you might want to show the number of orders per account - SELECT PAcontid, COUNT(PACONTNUMBER) FROM Table GROUP BY PAcontid

Comment: Do you want to include all columns in the select? Then you need to add all columns to the `GROUP BY` or use other aggregate functions like `MAX` for the other columns. You could also use a partitioning function like `ROW_NUMBER` in a cte, but then you need to tell us what records you want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `GROUP BY`, all the selected columns must be in the `GROUP BY` clause or, if not, an `aggregate` function (ex: `SUM`, `MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG`) around it!

For more info, check [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx).

---

In you case, a possible solution might be:

```
SELECT  MAX(PA01201.CUSTNMBR),
        MAX(PA01201.PACONTNUMBER),
        PA01201.PAcontid,
        MAX(PA01100.CUSTNMBR AS Expr1,
        MAX(PA01100.PAcontname),
        MAX(PA01100.PAcontid) AS Expr2,
        MAX(PA01100.PACONTNUMBER) AS Expr3,
        MAX(PA01201.PAprojname),
        MAX(PA01201.PAPROJNUMBER)
FROM       PA01201
INNER JOIN PA01100 ON PA01201.CUSTNMBR = PA01100.CUSTNMBR
       AND PA01201.PACONTNUMBER = PA01100.PACONTNUMBER
       AND PA01201.PAcontid = PA01100.PAcontid
GROUP BY PA01201.PAcontid
```

Answer (score 1):

Add all the selected columns in the `GROUP BY` clause. But first start with the desired column: `PAcontid`.

```
SELECT
    PA01201.CUSTNMBR, 
    PA01201.PACONTNUMBER, 
    PA01201.PAcontid, 
    PA01100.CUSTNMBR AS Expr1, 
    PA01100.PAcontname, 
    PA01100.PAcontid AS Expr2, 
    PA01100.PACONTNUMBER AS Expr3, 
    PA01201.PAprojname, PA01201.PAPROJNUMBER
FROM
    PA01201 
INNER JOIN
    PA01100 ON PA01201.CUSTNMBR = PA01100.CUSTNMBR AND 
    PA01201.PACONTNUMBER = PA01100.PACONTNUMBER AND 
    PA01201.PAcontid = PA01100.PAcontid 
GROUP BY 
    PAcontid, CUSTNMBR, PACONTNUMBER, PAcontname, PAprojname, PAPROJNUMBER
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean to "group" them by that visually but not in the same way SQL does, if you added an

```
   Order by CUSTNMBR , PAcontid
```

which will give you a list of customers on the left in order then the data in groups of PAcontid ..

or

```
   Order by PAcontid ,CUSTNMBR
```

which will sort it by PAcontid  and then put the customers in order..

Normally you would do say

```
ann apple 10
pete strawberry 3
Lucy strawberry 12

select fruit, sum(count) as total from lunch group by fruit
```

to get

```
apple 10
strawbery 15
```